# How can i create multiple threads cleaner?

Tags: c++, multithreading

so i creating multiple threads with the following way:

```
    std::thread Thread1(func1); Thread1.detach();
    std::thread Thread2(func2); Thread2.detach();
```

I doing that around 10 times, and it works perfectly fine, but
it just looks ugly, is there any method to do it cleaner? Thanks!

Comment: Just make a loop?

Comment: You don't need to give a name to each thread variable. `std::thread(func1).detach();` would work just as well. I this clean enough?

Comment: @IgorTandetnik Yeah, i knew about that. but i talking more about making it to take less lines

Comment: `for (auto f : {func1, func2}) std::thread(f).detach();`

Comment: `detach()` is usually a mistake. It leaves you with no control and awkward synchronization issues.

Comment: @PeteBecker I so agree with that, I usually opt for std::async with std::future, it has abstraction from threas, synchronization possibilities through future, AND you can pass data and exceptions between threads.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can achieve this syntax

```
for (auto func : { func1, func2 }) async(func);
```

with this example :

```
#include <chrono>
#include <functional>
#include <vector>
#include <thread>
#include <iostream>

void func1()
{
    std::cout << "1";
}

void func2()
{
    std::cout << "2";
}

// Make functions out of repeated things 
template<typename Fn>
void async(Fn fn)
{
    std::thread(fn).detach();
}

int main()
{
    for (auto func : { func1, func2 }) async(func);

    // I really don't like sleeps.
    // but async doesn't allow for any kind of synchronization
    // so allow for some time to pass so functions can show output
    std::this_thread::sleep_for(std::chrono::seconds(2));

    return 0;
}
```